# angular cli install command showing errors

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

I am trying to install angular cli on Windows 10, I have already installed npm and node, and have verified their version, they are above then what is required for angular cli to install but when I run install command on the prompt it show error.

[image]

Comment: try `npm cache clean` then re-run the command. Which version of Node/npm are you using?

Comment: node 8.21, npm 5.3.0

Comment: npm cache clean is also showing errors

Comment: Are you running this as an administrator? If not, you should be.

Comment: Please copy the text of the error into your post and, perhaps, also the relevant portions of debug log mentioned in the output.

Comment: i have uninstalled npm and node, then reinstalled them, and tried again to install and it worked :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have uninstalled npm and node, then reinstalled them, and tried again to install and it worked :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

first try to see node and npm is installed successfully using following commands on cmd

```
node -v
```

for node and it will return the version of node,then

```
npm -v
```

then it will return the version of npm after that in windows go to environment variables and see node environmental varible is there. after that

```
npm cache clean --force
```

use to clean the cache and go to users/Appdata/roaming and delete all the node modules in npm cache folder and restart your computer and give the following command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```